# How do I keep the tab bar from scrolling to the currently open tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have quite a few files open in vscode, so the tab bar at the top becomes scrollable. However whenevery I scroll to a different part of the tab bar (so that the currently displayed file is not visible) it jumps back after a while (maybe 30 seconds). How can I disable this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this same issue: [Tabs jump back to beginning when scrolling](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/133631)
.  A fix has been pushed to the Insiders Build.

> I pushed a change that the active tab will only get revealed when the
> size of the tab container changes. As such it can still happen that
> you get brought back to the active tab if an action is added or
> removed, but this should only happen in the very beginning and not
> later.

If possible, you should test the fix with the Insiders Build and report at the issue whether it was fixed for you or not.  In any case, v1.61 is due out pretty soon.